# Yaml file configuration some keys always returns Null Value

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes, yaml, appsettings

I have a very obscure problem, which I have been trying to solve for two or three days now.
I have a .Net core application, which I deployed in K8s.

Here is part of my code snippet.

```
public static async Task<MessageTranslationResDto> GetRedisCache(string uuid, string languageCode, string messageCode, string channel, IDistributedCache distributedCache, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    try
    {
        var URL = configuration["MessageTranslationService"];
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        var StartTimeAPI = DateTime.Now;
        var httpContent = new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(messageTransalationReqDto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, httpContent);
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageTranslationResDto>(responseContent);

        var redival = configuration["RedisExpiration"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(redival))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RedisExpiration is : " + redival);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RedisExpiration is not available");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

and the Yaml file as follows,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:  
  labels:
    app: ms-common
  name: ms-common-configmap
data:
  appsettings.common.json: |-
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "RabbitMQ": {
        "HostUrl": "*"
      }
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DMAIN": "***",
        "DADMIN": "***"
      },
      "Environment": "Dev",
      "Otlp": {
        "Endpoint": ""
      },
      "AspNetCoreInstrumentation": {
        "RecordException": "true"
      },
      "UseTracingExporter": "otlp",
      "UseMetricsExporter": "otlp",
      "ExceptionHandlingService": "",
      "RedisConnection": "***",
      "MessageTranslationService": "http://test/api/message",
      "RedisExpiration": "30"
    }

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ms-common
  name: ms-common-secret
data:  
  MessageTranslationService: dsdsdssd==
  ExceptionHandlingService: dsdsdsdsdsfs==
  RedisConnection: cm########wMA==
  ConnectionStrings__DMAIN: test1=
  ConnectionStrings__DADMIN: test==
type: Opaque
```

Problem is when taking the **`"RedisExpiration"`**, it always returns `null`. When getting congiguration values, `null` is returned only for this `"RedisExpiration"` value, other values ​​are received correctly. for example **`"MessageTranslationService"`**. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you please append your deployment/pod manifest to your question? :) So I can see how you pass in the env-variables or are you mounting the configmap? Are the values in the config-file even being used? The "MessageTranslationService" is defined multiple times, first in your JSON and second in your Secret.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to decode your value manually using base64?